# Shrink div on transition

Tags: jquery, html, css

With some help I have been able to get the a div to expand smoothly with a transition. Now I want to reverse it so that when the class changes it doesn't just disappear into thin air but close just as it opened.

I thought I would just be able to check the min-height and that would cause it to do the slide close in reverse. But that doesn't seem to work for me.

What am I doing wrong here?

```js
$(function() {
  $('.pp-post-banner-overlay').on('click', function() {
    let postFullId = $(this).attr('id');
    let postNumId = postFullId.slice(23);
    $('.pp-post-container').not('.element-invisible').addClass('element-invisible');
    jQuery('#pp-post-container-' + postNumId).removeClass('element-invisible');
  });
});
```

```css
.element-invisible {
  position: absolute !important;
  max-height: 0px;
  width: 100%;
  overflow: hidden;
  clip: rect(1px 1px 1px 1px);
  /* IE6, IE7 */
  clip: rect(1px, 1px, 1px, 1px);
}

.pp-post-container {
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100%;
  max-height: 9999px;
  min-height: 0px;
  -webkit-transition: max-height, min-height, 4s;
  -webkit-transition-timing-function: ease-in;
  transition: max-height, min-height, 4s;
  transition-timing-function: ease-in;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="pp-post-{post_id}" class="pp-post">
  <div id="pp-post-item-{post_id}" class="pp-post-item">
    <div id="pp-post-banner-overlay-{post_id}" class="pp-post-banner-overlay"></div>
  </div>
</div>
<div id="pp-post-container-{post_id}" class="pp-post-container element-invisible"></div>
```

Comment: Is there an example with the desired effect?

Answer (score 0):

It depends how do you want to achieve this.
Since your code isnt' working and you didn't provided a working jsfiddle I can try to give you a few alternatives:

Since you mentioned class "pp-post-banner-overlay" going to use it as selector:

on click:

```
$('.pp-post-banner-overlay').click(function() {
 $(this).fadeOut("slow", function() {
    $(this).removeClass("desiredClasstoRemove");
  });
});
```

On mouse leave

```
 $('.pp-post-banner-overlay').mouseleave( function() {
     $(this).fadeOut("slow", function() {
        $(this).removeClass("desiredClasstoRemove");
      });
    });
```

With CSS:
it's possible to add transions using only css. Apply to desired selector for example:

```
.pp-post-banner-overlay{
     transition: opacity 500 ease-in-out;
}
```

This is untested. But guess it should work.

André